# create SMB share on a clustered vm or dedicated server

Tags: virtual-machines, storage-area-network, server-message-block

I have a cluster that consists of 2 IBM servers, 8Gbps Fibre channel based SAN and 1 storage server (IBM Storwize v7000), i run virtualization on that cluster (Win2012 Hyper-V) but also want to use it's storage capacity as an SMB share. (It is going to be a multipurpose share for approx 200 users.)
Should i create a VM that is going to share the resources through virtualized SAN, or try to find a small server specifically for that purpose (i would have to connect it to the storage server through iSCSI because there is no way i'm getting those expensive HBA's).[quick sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ehxi.jpg)

Comment: If you have the filers (nas heads) you can do it directly from the v7k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a VM on the Hyper-V hosts to serve the SMB share, that way your users doesn't need direct access to the Storewize and management is a lot easier, especially if you're running Active Directory in your environment. It's also easier if you at some point get more storage or more hosts to move the VM around if it's not statically bound to the specific Storewize.

Another option if you are so inclined is to let the VM access the Storewize through iSCSI directly, but in my opinion that would only add unnecessary complexity.

Any reason why you wouldn't want to run a file sharing server as a VM?

Comment: I meant a dedicated physical server for sharing.                                  Storwize<---iSCSI-->DedicatedServer<----SMB---->Users
If i had HBA's for a new server that would be                                        Storwize<---FC----->DedicatedServer<----SMB---->Users                                                                                                     I had some concerns about vm performance, and never really heard about best practices in that field. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! These days I don't see any reason to run anything physical if you don't have a very specific need to, for example speciality hardware. If you notice any performance problems due to capacity deficiencies on your VM hosts, I'd put money into more hosts/bigger hosts instead of dedicated physical servers, management and operations will be much easier down the line that way!